# How can I set `strokeColor` without losing `foregroundColor` NSAttributedStringKey?

Tags: swift, swift4, nsattributedstring

Somebody say "Set minus value on `strokeWidth`", but it makes font thin. Do you have any ideas?

```
        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
            .foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
            .strokeColor : UIColor.black,
            .strokeWidth : 2.0,
        ]

        label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Sample", attributes:attributes)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of "makes font thin"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Somebody say 'Set minus value on strokeWidth'"* - that someone is [Apple itself](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1531/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007490):

> This is because the sign of the value for `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName` is interpreted as a mode; it indicates whether the attributed string is to be filled, stroked, or both. Specifically, a zero value displays a fill only, while a positive value displays a stroke only. A negative value allows displaying both a fill and stroke.

You do have a set a negative `strokeWidth` but the effective is imperceptible at small size (iOS 11 default font size is 14pt). Combined with pixel smoothing this makes for the appearance of the font appearing thinner. Here's the result of negative `strokeWidth` at 64pt:

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
    .foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
    .strokeColor : UIColor.black,
    .strokeWidth : -2,
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 64)
]
let text = NSAttributedString(string: "Sample", attributes:attributes)
```

[image: strokeWidth = -2]

And the result when `strokeWidth: -5`:

[image: strokeWidth = -5]

It appears "thicker" as you set `strokeWidth` deeper into the negative but neither is aesthetically pleasing. I'll leave it to you to decide on the look of your app.

Comment: Oh ... I had misunderstood. I can't draw `strokeWidth` around font, I see. Thank you very much.